# Why Monoid is not a requirement for foldr/foldl?

Tags: haskell, fold, monoids, foldable

I am looking at the `Foldable` class in Haskell. Two of the methods `fold`, `foldMap` requires a Monoid instance. But `foldr` or `foldl` don't have any such constraint.

```
fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

For the results of `foldr`/`foldl` to be equivalent, shouldn't it restrict the given folding function to be associative? Are there any examples where the results of foldr/foldl are different on the same list?

Shouldn't a Foldable instance wrap a Monoidal value? Or Foldable is more general?

Comment: Look at the types of the first functions of `foldr` and `foldl`. A monoid does not fit there.

Comment: @pdexter Nah, a Monoid is the only thing that really makes sense for the standard folds, because everything is treated as "sort of a list". Wherever types are treated as having a more complicated structure, the "left" and "right" in the name stop making sense. If you want to fold over anything that isn't a list, you'll really have to provide a more complicated algebra.

Comment: functional composition *is* associative: `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, `foldr (c :: (a -> b -> b)) :: b -> t a -> b`, **`c (x :: a) :: b -> b`**, so we get to compose `c x1`, `c x2`, ..., `c xn` in whatever order we like, because / IOW endofunctions *do* form a monoid, `Endo b`, all by themselves. With e.g. lists, `(x :) == ([x] ++)` , i.e. we can represent `c` as `c x = (f x <>)` with some suitable `f`, and `c x . c y ~= f x <> f y`. (or something like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For the results of `foldr`/`foldl` to be equivalent, shouldn't it restrict the given folding function to be associative? Are there any examples where the results of `foldr`/`foldl` are different on the same list?

Yes. If you pass a non-associative function (like subtraction `(-)`) you will absolutely get different results. And as you rightly point out there is no  `Monoid` instance that corresponds to something like `(-)`.

But that is by design. There is no such restriction on `Foldable` instances that `foldr` and `foldl` must take associative functions. There are situations where you might want to fold with something like subtraction. An instance of `Foldable f` is more interested in constraining what the `f` can do. The laws in particular are:

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t ) z
foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z
fold = foldMap id

-- if f is a Functor
foldMap f = fold . fmap f
foldMap f . fmap g = foldMap (f . g)
```

You can see in the sources that `foldr` by default does something clever with the `newtype Endo a = Endo (a -> a)` endomorphism monoid:

```
-- | Right-associative fold of a structure.
--
-- @'foldr' f z = 'Prelude.foldr' f z . 'toList'@
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z
```

to build a monoidal fold out of possibly non-monoidal `f` and `z`.

So ultimately the answer to the question "Why is Monoid not a requirement?" is the very boring "because it is more practical and, in the end, not necessary."

For more information I refer you to the paper that started it all, [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html).